# Separate 30 into three batches

Tags: mysql, jsp

[image]

There are 30 students in a classroom. I want to separate them into three batches by using mysql query in jsp.

Initially I did using the below query

```
connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL, "root", "student");
String queryString = "update student set batch=?,exam=? where studentid='"+studentid+"'  ";
pstatement = connection.prepareStatement(queryString);
pstatement.setString(1, batch);
pstatement.setString(2, exam);
```

Comment: Could you show us your error output?  Your query syntax might be a bit off.

Comment: sir i have added a snap shot please find

Comment: You haven't given us enough to help you, sorry.

Comment: sorry ill try to explain u here

Comment: define divide in three batches

Comment: in the above snap shot    when iam trying to assign   batchn no 1 to student_id 2 and batch no 2 to studweent_id 3     by using the above query   the query is setting batch only for first student only and rest of student it is assigning as null

Comment: as u see in red colored box iam setting batch numbers manually

Comment: sir  please help me here

Comment: your explanation is not clear. you mention 30 students and then only show two in the example. how do you decide which batch a student gets assigned to? how many per batch? you need to explain that and then we are more likely able to help you. saying your query isn't working correctly doesn't tell us enough to help you.

Comment: sir i said 30 students as an example     but there r two students for now   and i want to assign them in two different batches

Comment: please take your time to explain the problem, we cant read mind here so we need more information.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have privileges to comment but it would help to check if the UI was sending the second student info correctly. The query looks OK to me.